# How to fork mercurial repo while also forking subrepos

Tags: mercurial

I have a mercurial repo that has 5 sub repos (all mercurial on ssh servers).
I'd like to make a copy this repo and copies of all sub repos and put them on another server. Then on my workstation I need to push to those repos when pushing.

On my server so far I've done:

```
newserver> cd /my/newrepo/path
newserver> hg clone -U ssh://me@originalserver//my/repo/path
```

Followed by the commands on my worksatation:

```
workstation> hg clone ssh://me@newserver//my/newrepo/path
```

Then when I try to push, it pushes all subrepos to their original server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-read about [Subrepositories in Mercurial](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/subrepositories/), pay attention to ["Remote Subrepositories"](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/subrepositories/#remote-subrepositories) part.

In short: you have to rewrite subrepos definitions (make subrepositories local) by replacing URLs with relative path in `.hgsub` or clone each subrepository separately to `ssh://newserver` and changing URLs accordingly

**PS:** Username in ssh-URL is **BAD IDEA (tm)** - you have to use more natural HG-way of `[auth]` section in .hgrc